# Getting 500 error on Flight Inspiration Search API

Tags: amadeus

I just registered for your API and I'm trying to execute a Flight Search request. Currently getting this error message:

URL: https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/203/api-doc/3/api-docs-and-example/10001

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
      "detail": "DATA DOMAIN NOT FOUND FOR REQUEST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Are you able to assist?

Comment: Are you probably talking to the wrong people? This API does not belong stackoverflow. You should find out what an HTTP 500 error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the API under the test environment where the API works with a limited data collection, which means limited number of origin and destinations. You can find more information about the available data collection for each API in our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a brief explatnation of how it works from Amadeus Developer

> Flight Inspiration Search and Flight Cheapest Date Search are built on a pre-computed cache, it means these 2 APIs do not offer the full coverage of all possible origin-destination pairs but only a subset. We have performed a cache migration last week to improve the data coverage, data quality, and response time of the API. In order to have a full data domain with live data you need to use the Flight Offers Search API

This could mean that the flight details you are requesting might not exist in the cache hence the response. This has been the case for me :)